# How can I manage an element position attributes with Backbone.js?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

I have this multiplayer board game project, which has a **Board** *(being the Collection)* and many **Piece** objects (being the Model)*.

In order to display same board set up to all online players, how can I organize my Backbone code to update the **Piece's** `position` CSS attribute after a player moves that said **Piece**?

---

***Additional info:***

I'm using the Django framework on the server side, where every **Piece** object has a `id`, `x_position` and `y_position` attributes.

Comment: How are you moving the pieces (drag, mouse)? Have you written any preliminary Backbone code or are these just concepts?

Comment: Hi there, I'm going to use Jquery-ui Draggable interface to drag elements arround. For now, it's just conceptual code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS classes on the piece. Assuming your `x_position` is a range of a-z and your `y_position` is a range of 1-8 then

```
<div class="pawn <%= x_position+y_position %>">pawn</div>
```

And your CSS could look like

```
a1 { left:0; bottom:0; }
a2 { left:0; bottom:1em; }
/* and so on */
b1 { left:1em; bottom:0; }
/* and so on */
```

Listen to your draggable's `stop` event and work out which square it's in (it will provide you with the dropped position in the ui object (`ui.position.left` and `ui.position.top`). You can then apply the correct CSS class update the model, and clear the attributes the draggable has set.

Comment: In that sense, I would be referencing the the "square" position on each Piece CSS, so it could be rendered accordingly?